# Escape and unescape invalid characters

Tags: c#, security, escaping

This should be really easy. I have a string that i escape like the following:

```
string originalString = "M&M";
string escapedString = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(originalString);//M&amp;M
```

Good so far

```
string unEscapedString = System.Security.SecurityElement.FromString(escapedString).Text;
```

Expecting to go back to M&M but getting "object not set"

Assuming string should be in xml format so any help on what i should do in this case would be helpful.

Comment: `System.Security.SecurityElement.FromString()` doesn't return a `string` yet you assign its result to a `string`; is that a typo?

Comment: Yes i meant to put .Text at end. Thanks for catching

Comment: The `FromString` method expects XML; e.g. `string unEscapedString  = System.Security.SecurityElement.FromString($"<elementName>{escapedString}</elementName>");`

Comment: It just seem odd that they have escape function that takes any string but not the reverse.

Comment: The `FromString` is there to get a `SecurityElement` object from a string of XML, not to Unescape the value to a string. So, technically there is no _decode_ in the 'SecurityElement' object. It makes sense there would be a helper method to encode the value but not to decode it as you would be wanting the `SecurityElement` object to work with.

Comment: @Maxqueue Side note: you probably doing something wrong altogether... like constructing XML with string concatenation... You may want to stop for a second and think if there is better approach to achieve what you actually need...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`System.Net.WebUtility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=netframework-4.8) class's static [`HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebUtility_HtmlDecode_System_String_) method to do this:

```
string original = "M&M";
string escaped = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(original);
string unescaped = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(escaped);
```

---

The reason the code isn't working as you have it is because the `FromString` method expects valid xml. See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securityelement.fromstring?view=netframework-4.8):

> **Parameters**
>   `xml` [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8) 
>   The XML-encoded string from which to create the security element.

You can make your code sample work if you add xml tags around the string:

```
string unescaped = SecurityElement.FromString($"<x>{escaped}</x>").Text;
```

Comment: Yes this works and i already knew i could do this but don't understand why System.Security.SecurityElement has Escape but not the reverse?

Comment: Because `FromString` expects valid xml. I've updated the answer with a sample that should work for you.

Comment: Yes thank you and this seems like my best solution.